# Python3: Remove 'b' from string when writing to a file

Tags: python-3.x, string, type-conversion

I am using Python3 to forward incoming data form a tcp connection to a character device.
The code below is the part where I receive the data from the tcp stream. The data should all be interpreted as ASCII. Once a datagram of shape [...] is complete it should be sent to a character device file.

```
def tcp2devWorker(devwrt,tcp):
    tcp2devbuf="";
    while (1):
        chunk=str(tcp.recv(64));
        for b in range(len(chunk)):
            if chunk[b]=="[":
                tcp2devbuf="[";
            elif chunk[b]=="]":
                tcp2devbuf+="]";
                print("From TCP: ",tcp2devbuf);
                devwrt.write(tcp2devbuf);
                devwrt.flush();
            else:
                tcp2devbuf+=str(chunk[b]);
```

Print shows 'b' in front of every chunk. I thought it is an artifact of print. But is also shows in the character device. Output of print:

```
From TCP:  [)!!!!!!!!!!!!!!|SEFMTE8K#######################################'b'################################################################'b'################################################################'b'################################################################'b'#############################################################]
```

I read it has to do with the encoding but I dont get the concept right. Whatever way I encode and decode, can cannot get rid of the 'b's.

Can somebody point me at what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to remove `'b'` from `tcp2devbuf`. Then you can use `tcp2devbuf.replace("'b'","")`.

Like this

```
def tcp2devWorker(devwrt,tcp):
    tcp2devbuf="";
    while (1):
        chunk=str(tcp.recv(64));
        for b in range(len(chunk)):
            if chunk[b]=="[":
                tcp2devbuf="[";
            elif chunk[b]=="]":
                tcp2devbuf+="]";
                tcp2tcp2devbuf = devbuf.replace("'b'","")   # <---
                print("From TCP: ",tcp2devbuf);
                devwrt.write(tcp2devbuf);
                devwrt.flush();
            else:
                tcp2devbuf+=str(chunk[b]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint: It works when I insert tcp2devbuf=tcp2devbuf.replace("'b'",""). It looks like replace does not work "in place".

Comment: My bad. Changed it